# passing a string to a User Control

Tags: c#, string, parameters, user-controls, microsoft-metro

I'm approaching to Metro App world in this days, please be gentle. 
Here's the problem:

a page receives a string from another page

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Title.Text = e.Parameter.ToString();
}
```

and I need to pass this string to an User Control of the receiving page.

How can I pass a parameter from a page to an UserControl of another page?

Comment: add property to `UserControl` and set value to that property field?

Comment: ok but how can I pass "e.Parameter.ToString()" to the UserControl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

Add a property to your user control:

```
public string MyText { get; set; }
```

Give your user control a name.

```
<src:TopBarControl x:Name="MyTopBarControl" />
```

Then use your NavigatedTo method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var _TextParam = e.Parameter.ToString();
    this.MyTopBarControl.MyText = _TextParam;
}
```

This will feed your User Control what it needs.

You could also bind to it by setting the parameter to some public property of the page. If you attempt this approach, please remember to make the User Control's property a Dependency property and not a CLR property. I wrote an article on binding if you want a better explaination http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/xaml-binding-basics-101.html

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming usercontrol is part of navigated page, you have to do set Property of User Control on  `OnNavigatedTo` override.

Example:

```
 class MyUserControl : UserControl
 {
    public object Parameter {get;set;}
 }
```

Suppose this user control is part of `MyPage`

```
  class MyPage : Page
  {
    private MyUserControl myUserControl; // It is only for illustrations, Otherwise it goes to .designer.cs

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
       Title.Text = e.Parameter.ToString();
       myUserControl.Parameter = e.Parameter; // This is how to set the parameter in usercontrol.
     }
   }
```

Comment: What if the user control is not part of MyPage?

Comment: MyPage is just for illustration. The usercontrol must be part of some Page or Window that will be navigated. If it is WPF, there is a FrameControl, that can Navigate to UserControl.

Comment: ok, sorry for misunderstanding. By the way this is the actual situation: I call the user control from xaml with '<src:TopBarControl/>'; I've done the modifications you recommend me and added 'SectionTitle.Text = Parameter.ToString();' on the user control. I got a NullReferenceException. What I'm missing?

Comment: did you new up SectionTitle. `SectionTitle = new <type of SectionTitle>`